# Microsoft UWP sample camera frames run error: IP over USB Transport service (IpOverUsbSvc) is not available

Tags: windows, visual-studio, uwp

I downloaded all code examples from here:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/samples

I unzipped into my Windows 10 and opened solution "camera frames".

Builds ok but gets error when I run it.

I changed proj > props > Build > Platform from ARM to x64 and still get error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       DEP0001: Unexpected Error: SmartDeviceException - The IP over USB Transport service (IpOverUsbSvc) is not available. Retry after installing the IP over USB Transport service (Windows IP Over USB) through the Windows SDK installer. [0x80131500] CameraFrames
```

Cannot find solution to error or how to install …

```
IP over USB Transport service (Windows IP Over USB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was caused when I upgraded Visual Studio 2017 pro.

I solved the problem by doing this...

1. select Visual Studio Installer > Modify button > 
   select UWP & right-pane > UWP dev > Win 10 SDK LATEST.
2. select Visual Studio Installer > Modify button > select UWP & right-pane > UWP dev > Win 10 SDK LATEST.
3. install